# Adding image extension when there isn't one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the following script, I am going through every img source I have on the page, retrieving the extension and if there is no returned string, or not a know image type then I add .jpg

For some reason the if statement is true every time regardless of the extension.

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
 $(".main_img").each(function() {
        imgsrc = this.src;
        console.log(imgsrc);
        imgext = imgsrc.split('.').pop();
        $.trim(imgext);
        console.log(imgext);
          if(imgext != 'jpg' || imgext != 'jpeg' || imgext != 'gif'){
            console.log("Unacceptable,add extension");
            FinalURL = imgsrc + '.jpg';
        }
          else {
            console.log(imgext);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do your logs say the vale of imgext is?

Comment: The log outputs the extension as it should, for example jpg

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ge9sL2ok/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix for a bug in your code.

Just change the OR conditions to AND conditions and it will work.

Change this part:

```
if(imgext != 'jpg' || imgext != 'jpeg' || imgext != 'gif')
```

to this:

```
if(imgext != 'jpg' && imgext != 'jpeg' && imgext != 'gif')
```

It was not working because imgext will always be not equal to 3 different values simultaneously as suggested when using OR conditions in this case. Therefore, it will always come true. With AND, it will only accept if it is not equal to the value of either of the three. Should work.

Comment: It is working. would love you have an explanation..why didn't my approach work as intended ? EDIT: yea obviously my logic wasn't accurate.. :/ thx!

Comment: Added an explanation anyways :)

Comment: Yes assume if 1) imgext = txt than your `if` values are `true || true || true = true` 2) If imgext = jpg then `false || true || true  = true`. So the result is always `true`. If you use `!=` in two conditions mostly you have to use `AND` operator.